# json_decode - returning NULL

Tags: php, json, byte-order-mark

The below JSON string is being passed into `json_decode()`, and it is returning `NULL`.

```
{"total_goals":26,"total_games":17,"average_goals":"1.53"}
```

Here's my code:

```
$homeJSON = file_get_contents("http://strategy-bets.com/archive/archive.php?baseurl=http://www.totalcorner.com".$Home_Team_Link);

$homeJSON = str_replace("\xEF\xBB\xBF",'',$homeJSON); 
$homeJSON = rtrim($homeJSON);
$homeJSON = html_entity_decode($homeJSON);
$homeJSON = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $homeJSON);
$clean = rtrim($homeJSON, "\x00..\x1F");

$home_decoded = json_decode($clean);
```

`$home_decoded` is still `NULL`.

Comment: What is $Home_Team_link?

Comment: @Abitnew That doesn't really matter in this context. The example JSON is `{"total_goals":26,"total_games":17,"average_goals":"1.53"}`

Comment: is that the json in `$clean`?

Comment: What does `echo json_last_error();` after the `json_decode()` show?

Comment: @Will the number 4

Comment: That's `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX`, meaning the syntax of the JSON is invalid somehow. Can you show me a `var_dump($clean);`?

Comment: @Will - Clean: string(71) "{"total_goals":26,"total_games":17,"average_goals":"1.53"}"

Comment: The json syntax is perfectly valid, json_decode returns what one would expect.

Comment: @arkascha - This is why I am confused :)

Comment: Maybe you should tell us why you make those conversions to a perfectly innocent and valid json string.

Comment: @arkascha - I did this to rule out any BOM or other characters.

Comment: You don't do that in the json string, you do that in the decoded structure.

Comment: I can't decode it if it has BOM in it?

Comment: `"{"total_goals":26,"total_games":17,"average_goals":"1.53"} " ` - this is the var_dump without any conversion

Comment: If you receive a json value from an API that cannot be decoded, then the API is broken. Fix the cause, not the symptom.

Comment: Can you either provide the full URL passed to `file_get_contents()` or put the raw response returned by it (`var_dump($homeJSON);`) somewhere (here, pastebin)? Because when I `json_decode()` the result of your `var_dump()` above, it works correctly. But I'm not sure what's going on with the pre-processing you're doing between the initial URL request and encoding the JSON.

Comment: I have no problems whatsoever to decode a json string with trailing BOM.

Comment: @Will - try this: http://strategy-bets.com/archive/archive.php?baseurl=http://www.totalcorner.com/team/view/992

Comment: Thanks! Ok, see my answer and the edit I just added. I have it working now :) I know you were already trying to account for the UTF-8 BOM, but it seems that something about how you were removing the BOM wasn't working properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, [`json_decode()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is returning `NULL` due to an error condition. You can determine the nature of the error condition using [`json_last_error()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php), which returns an integer constant representing the type of error. You can decode these using this function (built from the error codes described on the `json_last_error()` manual page):

```
<?php
function decodeJsonError($errorCode)
{
    $errors = array(
        JSON_ERROR_NONE => 'No error has occurred',
        JSON_ERROR_DEPTH => 'The maximum stack depth has been exceeded',
        JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH => 'Invalid or malformed JSON',
        JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR => 'Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded',
        JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX => 'Syntax error',
        JSON_ERROR_UTF8 => 'Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded',
        JSON_ERROR_RECURSION => 'One or more recursive references in the value to be encoded',
        JSON_ERROR_INF_OR_NAN => 'One or more NAN or INF values in the value to be encoded',
        JSON_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_TYPE => 'A value of a type that cannot be encoded was given'
    );

    if (isset($errors[$errorCode]))
    {
        return $errors[$errorCode];
    }

    return 'Unknown error';
}
```

Now, I can't figure out exactly what the API you're calling is returned, because a valid link wasn't provided (and I understand this may be sensitive data), but, let's try a different approach, and just try to extract *only the JSON* from whatever the API is returning:

```
<?php

$homeJSON = file_get_contents("http://strategy-bets.com/archive/archive.php?baseurl=http://www.totalcorner.com".$Home_Team_Link);

if (!preg_match('/(\{"[^\}]+\})/', $homeJSON, $matches))
{
    echo "An error occurred; no JSON found.";
    return;
}

$home_decoded = json_decode($matches[1]);
```

This is working against the actual output from the API (without a proper URL) for me:

```
file_get_contents("http://strategy-bets.com/archive/archive.php?baseurl=http://www.totalcorner.com");
```

Even though the API itself is returning HTML mixed in with the JSON.

**Edit**: Since you provided a valid URL, I did some more debugging:

```
php > print_r(array_map('dechex', array_map('ord', str_split($homeJSON))));
Array
(
    [0] => ef
    [1] => bb
    [2] => bf
    [3] => 7b
    [4] => 22
    [5] => 74
    [6] => 6f
    [7] => 74
    [8] => 61
    [9] => 6c
    ...
```

Byte `7b` is the opening `{` where the valid JSON starts. Bytes `0-3` are a [UTF-8 Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). So, while my regex solution above will still work, we can also just clean up the BOM and any stray null characters like this:

```
$homeJSON = file_get_contents("http://strategy-bets.com/archive/archive.php?baseurl=http://www.totalcorner.com".$Home_Team_Link);

$homeJSON = trim($homeJSON, "\x0\xEF\xBB\xBF");

$home_decoded = json_decode($homeJSON);
```

This gives me:

```
php > var_dump(json_decode($jsonCopy));
object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
  ["total_goals"]=>
  int(26)
  ["total_games"]=>
  int(17)
  ["average_goals"]=>
  string(4) "1.53"
}
```